# Using Lists to represent BigInt

Tags: c++, class, integer, bigint

I'm trying to write my own implementation of a BigInt using lists to keep track of all the digits in a big integer. Each of the class implementation is in a seperate file.

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    node *next;
};


class LIST
{
    private:
        node *head;
    public:
    . . . 
};


class BigInt
{
    Private:
        LIST numList;
    Public:
        BigInt addNum(BigInt& b);
        . . .
};
```

How can I implement the addNum method for the by BigInt class? I know how to add the data in two lists given the head pointer, but in my BigInt class I can't access the head pointer of the list class so how can i do this? Any tip would be appreciated.

Instructions for assignment:

Create a linked-list-based arbitrary-precision unsigned integer class BigInt. You 
may create the linked list the simple way, without bothering with carrier elements in the 
list, e.g., just make a struct that holds a digit and next pointer. You may manage the 
linked list within the BigInt class itself, or alternatively, you may use a linked list 
class as a member (by aggregation/composition) of the BigInt class to manage the 
list of digits. BigInt will also need to keep the size (how many decimal digits are in 
the number), and a print width (defaulting to the size of the number).

For the BigInt class, implement normal (unsigned long long int parameter), copy 
and default (set to 0) constructors, a method to assign an arbitrary unsigned long long int 
to the BigInt (which the constructors may use), a method to add two BigInts 
returning a new BigInt with the result, a method to multiply two BigInts 
returning a new BigIntT with the result, a method to return the number of decimal 
digits in the BigInt, an assignment = operator, and a destructor.

Comment: Can you add a get_head_pointer() method to class LIST?

Comment: No, the purpose is to encapsulate the list implementation other than a simple public interface that allows you to add/remove/print(iterator) list elements.

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework? If you think the assignment requires that you add two numbers without being able to look at the digits, I'm afraid you've misunderstood it. You need to clarify, either with your professor or to us, in exactly what way you are permitted to access the contents of numList from class BigInt.

Comment: It would seems I'm misunderstanding something. I've put the exact instructions for the assginment.

Comment: Where does it say you can't add an iterate method to the linked list class? Or even that you can't add a getter method of the head pointer? Just make an iterator for the list of each operand to add and sum each digit in turn. Also, shouldn't add return a pointer to a BigInt rather than a BigInt itself? You're going to have to allocate memory for a new object when adding, right?

Comment: Yes, the add does return a pointer to BigInt. So for the iterator for each operand, I pass in the head pointer to start iterating?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a doubly linked list might be an even better idea http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list. When you think about adding two digits, if the sum is greater than 9 you need to carry. A doubly linked list would be really useful for this.

Your class would look like this:

class Node{

int val;
   Node *next;
   Node *previous;9

}